# Initialization of Xgboost DMatrix reduce features number

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to understand following case:

1. when I create new `xgbost` DMatrix

   `xgX = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=Y, missing=np.nan)`
2. based on input data **X**  with 64 features
   [image]
3. I got the new DMatrix with 55 features
   [image]

What the magic is doing here? Any advise would be great!

Comment: Is there any way to move my question to `DataScience stack` http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at
[xgboost issue #1223](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1223)

There, khotilov makes the comment:

> The problem with CSR is that when you have completely sparse columns at the end, you cannot figure out that they exist by just looking at CSR's indices and pointers.

The consequence of this is that the function that creates the `DMatrix`from `X`, `XGDMatrixCreateFromCSR`, does not account for the empty columns at the end, which in your case is 9 columns. You may want to check that in your case and determine whether or not you really have 64 features in `X`.